# TypeError: server.views is not a function in hapi.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am a beginner on node.js I am using hapi framework for my web app. In that i am using handlebars for template. When i configure the server views i am getting the type error.

```
    'use strict';

    const hapi = require('hapi');
    const server = new hapi.Server();
    const inert = new require('inert');

    server.connection({
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 8080,
    });

    //Starting server
    server.start((error) => {
        if(error){
            throw error;
        }
        console.log("Server running" + server);
    });

    server.register(inert, () => {
        console.log("hhh");
        server.views({  
            engines: {
                html: require('handlebars')
            },
            path: 'views',
            layoutPath: 'views/layout',
            layout: 'default',
            partialsPath: 'views/partials'
            //helpersPath: 'views/helpers',
        });
    });
```

I getting this error:

```
    TypeError: server.views is not a function
at server.register (/home/developer/Workspace/kravein-test/app/backend/server.js:22:9)
at process.nextTick (/home/developer/Workspace/kravein-test/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:854:22)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
at Module.runMain (module.js:577:11)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:144:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:467:3
```

I am using hapi 15.0.3. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For making use of `server.views`, you would need the [Vision plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vision)

e.g. with Handlebars

```
const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 8000 });

const handler = function (request, reply) {

    reply.view('basic/index', {
        title: 'examples/views/handlebars/basic.js | Hapi ' + request.server.version,
        message: 'Hello World!'
    });
};

server.register(require('vision'), (err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    server.views({
        engines: { html: require('handlebars') },
        path: __dirname + '/templates'
    });

    server.route({ method: 'GET', path: '/', handler: handler });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Huw Davies. It works. I saw the tutorial on https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-create-a-dynamic-handlebars-layout-template-in-hapijs here. But in this they never used vision plugin. Also on some other tutorials also i checked they never used it. Its based on hapi version?

Comment: I don't understand quite what you mean by 'based on hapi version'? @Sivabalan

Comment: To use server.views() in hapi 15.0.3 should we include vision?

Comment: Yes, to use server.views in any situation you need vision. It's not included in the hapi npm module