# Handling reply.view with @types/hapi

Tags: typescript, hapi.js

I have been using hapi with typescript. I was able to write this:

```
export function displaySignupForm(request: Hapi.Request, reply: Hapi.IReply) {
  reply.view("users/signup");
}
```

This worked.

The latest update of @types/hapi is 16.1.6, which has backward incompatible changes. The above code doesn't work. I understand now there is `ReplyWithContinue` and `ReplyNoContinue`. But I couldn't find a type that includes `reply.view`.

Which type in the latest `@types/hapi` has `reply.view`?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39478689/typeerror-server-views-is-not-a-function-in-hapi-js

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong reply interface. It's `Hapi.ReplyNoContinue`

Answer (score 0):

`server.views` and `reply.view` are decorations provided by the [Vision](https://github.com/hapijs/vision) plugin, so they are rightfully excluded from the @types/hapi definitions.